# Windows Phone append to XML file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xml-serialization

I am trying to save data as xml using the following code

```
 StorageFile file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename,
        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        // Serialize the object
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

        // Write the data from the textbox.
        using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            try
            {
                s.Position = s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                serializer.Serialize(s, obj);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally{
                s.Close();
            }
        }
```

This results in an xml of the format :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tasks xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Task>task1</Task>
  <Group>group</Group>
  ....
</Tasks>
```

The **problem**
When I append to the file I get something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tasks xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Task>task1</Task>
  <Group>group</Group>
  ....
</Tasks><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tasks xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Task>task2</Task>
  <Group>group</Group>
  ....
</Tasks>
```

This prevents the data from being deserialized, how do I avoid writing the metadata ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `XmlTextWriter` ([XmlTextWriter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx)) to have more control over the XML.  Please try the following:

```
    StorageFile file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    // Serialize the object
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

    // Write the data from the textbox.
    using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        try
        {
            s.Position = s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

            using (var x = XmlWriter.Create(s, new XmlWriterSettings(){OmitXmlDeclaration = true}))
            {
                x.Setting.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
                serializer.Serialize(x, obj);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally{
            s.Close();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** Replaced `new XmlTextWriter` by `XmlWriter.Create`

Comment: XmlTextWriter doesnt seem to be available for windows phone

Comment: Do you have `XmlWriter.Create`?

Comment: Check the updated code above.  I replaced `new XmlTextWriter` by `XmlWriter.Create`.